# Adding Authentication to SOAP header in .net issue

Tags: .net, authentication, soap

I'm trying to add authentication to a web service that I've been consuming with no issues until now, however seem to be having a problem. I think the credentials are authenticating, but getting "The type XXX was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."

In my SoapExtension class I'm using:

```
public class AuthHeaderExtension : SoapExtension
{
    public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
    {
        switch (message.Stage)
        {
            case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
                if (message is SoapClientMessage)
                {
                    AddAuthHeader(message);
                }
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
                break;
        }
    }
    private void AddAuthHeader(SoapMessage message)
    {
        var clientId = "xxx";
        var password = "yyy";

        var authheader = new AuthHeader
        {
            ClientID = clientId,
            Password = password
        };
        message.Headers.Add(authheader);
    }

    public override object GetInitializer(Type serviceType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, SoapExtensionAttribute attribute)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void Initialize(object initializer)
    {
        return;
    }
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthHeaderExtensionAttribute : SoapExtensionAttribute
{
    public override Type ExtensionType
    {
        get { return typeof(AuthHeaderExtension); }
    }


    public override int Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return 100;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling this at the start of every request in the reference itself simply using

```
[AuthHeaderExtension]
```

The error about invalid credentials has stopped, but instead I'm getting the error as mentioned above. I've added custom SOAP headers in this way before, however never for authenticating with credentials.

There are a bunch of pages on here about that error message but don't seem to be related to the same problem. Any help at all would be appreciated?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, by adding the following into the reference.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIncludeAttribute(typeof(AuthHeader))]
```